# Angular-6: Convert string to array of a custom object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have this produced **string**:

```
string str = [{"id":1,"name":"Angular"},{"id":2,"name":"SpringBoot"}]
```

I'd like to convert it to an **array of Objects** to have that:

```
listexps: Expertise[];
listexps = [{"id":1,"name":"Angular"},{"id":2,"name":"SpringBoot"}];
```

And **Expertise** class is

```
export class Expertise
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

I tried that:

```
let array = str .replace('[{','').replace('}]','').split("},{").map(String);
```

but that didn't resolve my problem, I got:

```
"id":1,"name":"Angular","id":2,"name":"SpringBoot"
```

instead of

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Angular"},{"id":2,"name":"SpringBoot"}];
```

Have you please any idea about solving that ?.
Big thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need is [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp); it converts string to an object;

relevant **ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Expertise {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  strIntoObj: Expertise[];

  constructor() {
    let str: string = '[{"id":1,"name":"Angular"},{"id":2,"name":"SpringBoot"}]';
    this.strIntoObj = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(this.strIntoObj);
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r8q8pb)